# Conda command (>> conda info --envs) now shows all environments TWICE, after changing .condarc

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I added the directory "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs" the default in the conda config file ".condarc"), so now my .condarc file looks like this:

```
ssl_verify: true
channels:
  - defaults
envs_dirs:
  - C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs
```

Now when I run the command "conda info --envs" my system lists all environments TWICE (see below!)

I cannot figure out why all environments now appear twice.  The one environment named "C:\Users\richadmin.conda\envs\TOPSS" was created before I made the configuration change in ".condarc".

Here's the response that I get when I type at the command prompt.

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda info --envs
# conda environments:
#
                      *  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
RStudio                  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\RStudio
convertapi               C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\convertapi
icarra_py2               C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\icarra_py2
kedro_pipelines          C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\kedro_pipelines
python27base             C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python27base
quant_trader             C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\quant_trader
quantecon                C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\quantecon
rstudio                  C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\rstudio
webscrapers              C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\webscrapers
TOPSS                    C:\Users\richadmin\.conda\envs\TOPSS
base                     c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
convertapi               c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\convertapi
icarra_py2               c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\icarra_py2
kedro_pipelines          c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\kedro_pipelines
python27base             c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\python27base
quant_trader             c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\quant_trader
quantecon                c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\quantecon
rstudio                  c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\rstudio
webscrapers              c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\webscrapers
```

I can live with it, but it bothers me to see things twice, one with upper case (RStudio and rstudio) as though they were different environments, and others showing only once.

Does anyone have any explanation for why the lists shows the environments TWICE?

Thank you.

###################################
Some SO responders asked for conda info data:

```
# conda info

     active environment : topss
    active env location : C:\Users\richadmin\.conda\envs\topss
            shell level : 2
       user config file : C:\Users\richadmin\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\richadmin\.condarc
          conda version : 4.8.3
    conda-build version : not installed
         python version : 3.7.1.final.0
       virtual packages : __cuda=10.1
       base environment : c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\richadmin\.conda\pkgs
                          C:\Users\richadmin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs
                          c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\richadmin\.conda\envs
                          C:\Users\richadmin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.8.3 requests/2.23.0 CPython/3.7.1 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.18362
          administrator : True
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

#######################

## conda config --show envs_dirs

envs_dirs:

- C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs
- c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs
- C:\Users\richadmin.conda\envs
- C:\Users\richadmin\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs

Comment: That is indeed unexpected. I think the output of `conda info` could be helpful for understanding the problem.

Comment: I'm with @.cel, show the `conda info` or at least `conda config --show envs_dirs`. I suspect its getting picked up from somewhere else (possibly an environment variable like `CONDA_ENVS_DIRS`). Also, did this persist even after starting a new shell session? I have the default in my `.condarc` and it does not behave like this (though **osx-64** platform).

Comment: Yes, these double listings persist after restarting the computer and all environments and tools.  See the results of ```conda info``` and ```conda config --show envs_dirs``` above.

Answer (score 1):

The `envs_dirs` variable has the same directory listed twice, but with case variant (`c:\` versus `C:\`). I'd venture removing one of the variants, e.g.,

```bash
conda config --remove envs_dirs 'c:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs'
```

would resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

delete duplicated envs listing in `environments.txt` file in the `.conda` folder.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the answer from @adamthrz, this helped me:

- Open `C:\Users\your_name\.conda\environments.txt`, delete duplicated envs.

I found this folder with command `conda config --show envs_dirs`.

Answer (score 1):

I use `conda` from Miniforge and had the same problem.
The solution proposed by @adamthrz and @Tiancheng YANG worked for me.

Actually, to see the folders that concerne the environments, type:

```
> conda config --show envs_dirs
envs_dirs:
  - C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Local\miniforge3\envs
  - C:\Users\my_user\.conda\envs
  - C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
```

Folder `C:\Users\my_user\.conda\envs` contains the file `environments.txt`
In this file, I had my paths to the environments cited twice, with the difference of the capital letter on the drive.

```
C:\Users\my_user\AppData\Local\miniforge3\envs\my_env
c:\Users\my_user\AppData\Local\miniforge3\envs\my_env
```

I deleted one line and it solved the problem.